# Trying to determine length of time from a set date to current date from a table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have an employees table:

[image]

I am trying to determine the length of time certain employees - e.g. Luke and Helen - have been working since the start date up to now, along with the Team they belong to.

So far I can show the table based on their name and team eg:

```
SELECT EmployeeName, Team 
FROM employees 
WHERE EmployeeName  in ('Luke', 'Helen');
```

But I am having issues trying to show the table with the length of time each employee has been in the company:

```
SELECT EmployeeName, Team, count (*) AS Tenure
FROM 
(
    SELECT EmployeeName, Team
    FROM employees
    WHERE dateddiff(mm, StartDate, getdate()) AND EmployeeName  in ('Luke', 'Helen')
    )a
GROUP BY EmployeeName, department;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the columns that you want.  These appear to be:

```
SELECT EmployeeName, Team, DATEDIFF(month, StartDate, getdate())
FROM employees
WHERE EmployeeName IN ('Luke', 'Helen');
```

The `DATEDIFF()` goes in the `SELECT`, not the `WHERE`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much, i was going down a rabbit hole here for quite some time trying to get the date syntax set up, cheers Gordon